# Mount a LUKS partition at boot

Tags: 10.04, luks, encrypted-partition

I have installed an Ubuntu machine with two [encrypted LUKS partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto3): one for `/` and one for `/home`.

I've reinstalled the machine to upgrade to 10.04. Again, the `/` is installed using LUKS, and I'm able to mount the `/home` using:

```
mkdir /media/home
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 home
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/mapper/home /media/home
```

The problem is, this cryptfs mapper disappears after boot, so I putting the appropriate line in fstab fails.

How do I set the cryptfs to prompt for password and unlock the drive **at boot**?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems that I needed to edit the `/etc/crypttab` file, which is the crypto equivalent to `fstab`, and add the following line:

```
# create a /dev/mapper device for the encrypted drive
home    /dev/sda2       none luks
```

And add the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /home LUKS
/dev/mapper/home /home ext4 rw 0 0
```

Now I get two password prompts at boot, as needed.

Comment: you would also have to update the initramfs image with `update-initramfs` for this change to take effect.

Comment: Is this still applicable for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Answering my own (immediately above) question: our initial tests show that it (this answer) does still apply and work on 20.04.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem!!  However, everything is taken care of after this command!  You should try it out :-)

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: Care to explain what that command does?

Comment: @Flimm , the command re-create your ramdisk , for all the kernel installed.  You might configured crypttab , but this needs to be copied into your ramdisk , if you use a crypted root

Comment: This answer should include an in-depth explanation, it is not clear that it relates to the question at all.