# Full Disk Encryption with LUKS: auto mount second volume

Tags: 11.10, encryption, luks

TrueCrypt on Windows can auto mount volumes that use the same passphrase as the boot volume. You enter the passphrase only once. Is there a way to do this with LUKS?

Background: I'm currently migrating from Windows to Ubuntu. I set up Ubuntu 11.10 with LUKS full disk encryption. I use a second hard drive that is still a TrueCrypt NTFS volume. I want to change that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mount a LUKS partition at boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21025/mount-a-luks-partition-at-boot)

Comment: "possible duplicate of Mount a LUKS partition at boot" Not really, with that method you still have to enter your passphrase once for each disk.

Comment: Yes you have to enter a password for each disk. If you want to enter a single password, use LVM.

Comment: How exactly would this be done with LVM? Is there a specific howto on adding an addition drive to a logical volume? (responding to bodhi.zazen's last comment)

Comment: Contrary to what has already been said, you CAN use password files that are on the first encrypted volume.

Comment: It's in part of this answer if you're in a hurry, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36434/install-backtrack-5-r2-into-running-luks-setup-installed-with-ubuntu/36490#36490

Comment: Now with SSD + Hard drive in my laptop, I'm in the same situation. It's possible using a keyfile as mentioned [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=765525#p765525). Will investigate soon probably and post as an answer if I succeed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `decrypt_keyctl` keyscript to securely cache the passphrase when mounting multiple encrypted volumes. The [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/quantal/cryptsetup/quantal/view/head:/debian/README.keyctl) describes how to do this on boot; there are some caveats with workarounds described in [bug 1022815](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1022815/comments/7).

This should allow auto mounting of multiple encrypted volumes at boot with only one passphrase prompt. The same keyctl mechanism could be used to arrange the automounting of other volumes after boot time, but I'm not aware of a full solution.

Comment: This is the [upstream repo](https://github.com/gebi/keyctl_keyscript); at this time it's more current than the cryptsetup/saucy package by one commit (other times the opposite is true).