# "merging" multiple hardrives for Ubuntu 14.04 install

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, hard-drive, system-installation, filesystem

I have 3 hardrives inside my laptop 2 of which currently house other opperating systems but have a empty partitions of 8 and 9 gigabye and the third is just 12 gB (currently not partitioned at all). Now each of these 3 is to small to be useful to me, however combined they are 29gigs which can easily hold a ubuntu installation, and associated programs. Is there a way set up my installation in such a way that it threads these 3 disks as one? Or is there a way by which I can make it default storage of many things into one drive (downloads and sudo apt-get install for example) to one drive while keeping ubuntu onto another?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with LVM as documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219881/how-can-i-create-one-logical-volume-over-two-disks-using-lvm) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7002/how-to-set-up-multiple-hard-drives-as-one-volume/7841#7841). But 14.04 now supports btrfs, so I would give that a try:

- Make a partition on each disk to take up the free space
- `mkfs.btrfs -d single /dev/sdxx /dev/sdyy /dev/sdzz`
- If you want to check the filesystem, do `mount /dev/sdxx /mnt; df -h; umount /mnt` - df will show the total space of all three devices
- In Ubuntu installer, select manual partitioning ("something else"), select your btrfs filesystem (any of the 3 devices), set type "btrfs" and mount point "/". Do not check the "format?" checkbox. Click "install now" - the installer will warn "The filesystem... has not been marked for formatting", just click continue.
- Do the rest of the install as normal

For further details on this approach see [Btrfs wiki - Using btrfs with multiple devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices).

Comment: Is this before or after installing the new ubuntu installation? I assume it's before but just to be sure?

Comment: Before. Make sure you get the partitions right, don't format your existing ones.

Comment: I keep getting "cannot detect existing filesystems use -f option to forice overwrite and if I add -f then I get "could not open /dev/sda3 error checking /dev/sda3 mount status, I have tried with both sda3 mounted and unmounted neither seem to work.

Comment: Make sure the partitions are unmounted (`lsblk` and `cat /proc/mounts`) before you format them. You could also check the partition type is 83 (Linux) - in theory it does not matter, but it is better to set it correctly.