# Extend partition with the free space of other disk?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, tty

I have a 8GB `/` partition and free 4TB on the other disk. 
First disk's partitions are `/dev/sda1` and `/sda2` and the second disk's is `/dev/sdc`. 
Is it possible to extend the `/` partition with the free space of the second disk?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem    Size   Used   Avail    Use%    Mounted on
udev          3.9G      0    3.9G      0%    /dev
tmpfs         794M    79M    715M     10%    /run
/dev/sda2     7.2G   7.2G       0    100%    /
tmpfs         3.9G      0    3.9G      0%    /dev/shm
tmpfs         5.0M      0    5.0M      0%    /run/lock
tmpfs         3.9G      0    3.9G      0%    /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     98M    98M       0    100%    /snap/core/10444
/dev/loop1     98M    98M       0    100%    /snap/core/10185
/dev/md0       14T    26M     14T      1%    /mnt/zm
tmpfs         794M      0    794M      0%    /run/user/1000
```

Comment: If you are using logical volumes, then yes. It’s not too complicated, either.

Comment: @Matigo any tips or guides on how to do it without gui?

Comment: Are you using logical volumes? Can you update your question to include the output of `df -h` and `sudo lvdisplay`? This will make it easier to confirm things and provide more specific details.

Comment: @Matigo added df -h, sudo lvdisplay returns nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create one logical volume over two disks using LVM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219881/how-can-i-create-one-logical-volume-over-two-disks-using-lvm)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks, I will try it and give a feedback later.

Comment: Looks like you do not have an LVM in place, which will complicate things a bit. The most logical solution may be to move your `/home` directory and, if you have various services like a database or web server running, perhaps some of those, too. The output of `df -h` shows you have a 14TB device, but your question says 4TB. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Matigo I'm pretty bad at it, I used ```sudo lsblk``` and it returned that md0 disk consists of 4gb parts. I thought that I'd use only one 4gb part (/dev/sdc).

Comment: It is also possible with `btrfs`. `ext4` can be converted to `btrfs`.