# How to use storage available in two SSDs together?

Tags: mount, 22.04, ssd, google-drive

I have a notebook with Ubuntu 22.04LTS installed (no dual boot). It has two SSDs disk: one with 1TB and another one with 512Gb. I have more than 1TB in my Google Drive and I would like to have my files available locally too. Hence, I would need to use both SSDs together in order to have enough storage for that. How can I do that? I would also like to do so in a safe fashion, so please let me know if there are any risks to doing that.

I have added some extra information below. I am unsure what information is important sharing to get a meaningful answer to this question, but if you need more info just comment and I will edit the question! Thanks for your help!

By running `df -x squashfs` I get the following output:

```
Syst. Archives    1K Blocks      Used  Available Usage% Mounted in
tmpfs                800216      2416     797800   1%   /run
/dev/sda3         959783984 910971452          0 100%   /
tmpfs               4001068     30892    3970176   1%   /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5120         4       5116   1%   /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1       204580      5360     199220   3%   /boot/efi
tmpfs                800212       156     800056   1%   /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4    480612276   9326144  446798948   3%   /media/roberto/RAIZ
/dev/nvme0n1p3      5074592   3593948    1202116  75%   /media/roberto/RECOVERY
```

The two system archives I am interested in putting together are `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/nvme0n1p4`. `/dev/sda3` is the one where I currently have all my stuff saved and where all my programs are installed. `/dev/nvme0n1p4` is mounted in `/media/roberto/RAIZ`, and RAIZ means ROOT.

Comment: Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219881/how-can-i-create-one-logical-volume-over-two-disks-using-lvm) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7002/how-to-set-up-multiple-hard-drives-as-one-volume?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thanks, this is somewhat helpful. I feel these instructions are meant when you either have you system installed in a different partition, correct? In my case, I have my system in /dev/sda3 (if I am getting it right), as well as my files, and I want to join it with /dev/nvme0n1p4. So I am worried that the process described will either delete my files, my OS, or both. Is that a reasonable fear and what should I do to avoid that?

Comment: If you can wipe all data and start fresh LVM is the way to go, you may loose all the data if one disk breaks and with two disk you have double the risk. I would designate the nvme as /home/roberto and move some from the sda3 partitions. I like ncdu to find the biggest files/directories and clean those up.