# Encrypted LVM on multiple drives

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm, luks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full Disk Encryption with LUKS: auto mount second volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113539/full-disk-encryption-with-luks-auto-mount-second-volume)

I want to set up encrypted LVM when I install Ubuntu. I have an SSD and an HDD and I would like to put `/boot`, swap and all the other mount points on the SSD but put `/home` on the HDD. I want to use the same passphrase for both drives. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are some other ways than done in that duplicate question.

You can use LUKS keyfiles stored somewhere in your encrypted rootfs to automatically unlock your home partition, just make sure non-root users can't read it.
Alternatively, you can use LVM (basically acting as RAID to get one big volume) -> LUKS-> LVM. And make sure your physical extents are located in the right drive.