# How to mount a luks encrypted partition at boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, encryption, luks

I have been given a task to creat a LUKS encrypted partition and then mount it, here are the steps I followed:

1. Create the partition for encryption:

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sda
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Format the partition with cryptsetup:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda3
   ```
4. Open encrypted partition:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 secret-disk
   ```
5. Add the following to `/etc/crypttab`:

   ```
   secret-disk       /dev/sda3
   ```
6. Make filesystem on partition:

   ```
   sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/mapper/secret-disk
   ```
7. Make mount directory:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /secret
   ```
8. Add the following to `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/secret-disk   /secret   ext4 defaults 1 2
   ```
9. Mount partition at /secret:

   ```
   sudo mount /secret OR sudo mount -a
   ```
10. Reboot.

Problem: During reboot, the mount instruction in `fstab` returns the `error : device not ready or not present`. And I have to enter `S` to skip the mount so ubuntu can boot or `M` to recover it manually. I have checked this [option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21025/mount-a-luks-partition-at-boot) but it does not solve mine. How do I get the encrypted partition to mount at `/secret`.

Comment: See this answer to boot with a hashed keyfile, no password entry needed.
https://serverfault.com/a/497427/566986. This is handy when using VM from inside a Veracrypt volume and other situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add this `secret-disk   /dev/sda3   none luks` to the `/etc/crypttab` file as admin and reboot. The passphrase will be requested, and the encrypted partition unlocked.