# I somehow managed to break my hard drive - Please help

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am trying to access a full disk encrypted hard drive (sda) on my computer that holds a Linux Mint 18 install but I am unable to get it to mount. My current installation is on the same computer but on a different drive. (sdb)

I cannot boot from this drive. If I try the message is that it has no file system to boot from.

lsblk shows:

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   487M  0 part  
├─sda2                                          8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                                          8:5    0 465.3G  0 part  
  └─luks-d1e57395-383f-4e0e-8be5-e4726f21adda 252:4    0 465.3G  0 crypt 
sdb                                             8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                                          8:17   0   487M  0 part  /boot
├─sdb2                                          8:18   0     1K  0 part  
└─sdb5                                          8:21   0 465.3G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt                                252:0    0 465.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─mint--vg-root                           252:1    0 457.3G  0 lvm   /
    └─mint--vg-swap_1                         252:2    0     8G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1                            252:3    0     8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

e2fsck:

```
sudo e2fsck /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1: clean, 305/124928 files, 77714/498688 blocks

sudo e2fsck /dev/sda2
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2
Could this be a zero-length partition?

sudo e2fsck /dev/sda5
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda5 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

I can mount sda1 but when I try to mount sda2 the terminal shows:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

and sda5:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

So I don't really know what I am doing which is probably why I have this problem in the first place but I was hoping somebody could help me to be able to mount the hard drive, if only read only, so I can pull some important files from it. I know my crypt password. Is there a way I can recover this data. Perhaps I can rebuild the file system?

Edit:
I tried to mount sda5:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 samsung
[sudo] password for user: 
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5:
```

then:

```
/media/samsung $ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/samsung /media/samsung/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/samsung,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount a LUKS partition at boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21025/mount-a-luks-partition-at-boot)

Comment: Linux Mint is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your drive is a LUKS container which most likely contains a LVM volume group. Before proceeding, make sure that you have `cryptsetup` and `lvm2` installed.

1. Open the container:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 samsung
   ```
2. Activate the LVM logical volumes:

   ```
   sudo vgchange -aay
   ```
3. Check what you now have in `lsblk`:

   ```
   sudo lsblk
   ```